# Closing a menu on anywhere click

Tags: javascript, search, server, load, gzip

I am working on a website and here is the link file:///D:/fahim/HTML/menu/index.html. If you click the menu its closing on its own "X" button, but i want it to close by clicking outside the menu. This is the javascript used on the home page.

```js
<script>
var popupView = new popup();

document.querySelector('#btn_1').addEventListener('click', function () {
popupView.show(document.querySelector('#popup_1'));
});

document.querySelector('#btn_2').addEventListener('click', function () {
popupView.show(document.querySelector('#popup_2'), function () {
 console.log('show do something');
});
});

document.querySelector('#btn_3').addEventListener('click', function () {
popupView.show(document.querySelector('#popup_3'), '', function () {
 console.log('CLOSE');
});
});

</script>
```

And this is the code which is attached as popup_view.js file on server

```js
(function () {
    var popup = function() {
        function hide(dom, dosomething) {
            if (!dom) {
                console.error('hide function not set dom object');
                return;
            }
            if (dosomething) {
                dosomething();
            }
            dom.className += ' ' + 'popup_hide';
        }
        function show(dom, dosomethingShow, dosomethingClose) {
            if (!dom) {
                console.error('show function not set dom object');
                return;
            }
            if (dosomethingShow) {
                dosomethingShow();
            }
            var className = 'popup_hide',
                reg = new RegExp('(^|\\b)' +
                    className.split(' ').join('|') +
                    '(\\b|$)', 'gi');
            dom.className = dom.className.replace(reg, '').trim();
            var nodes = dom.childNodes;
            for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (nodes[i].className === 'pop_up_close') {
                    var close = function (e) {
                        if (dosomethingClose) {
                            dosomethingClose();
                        }
                        dom.className += ' ' + 'popup_hide';
                        nodes[i].removeEventListener('click', close);
                    };
                    nodes[i].addEventListener('click', close);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        this.show = show;
        this.hide = hide;
    };
    window.popup = popup;
})();
```

Please help as i have tried lot of codes except these but non of them works

Comment: `$(document).on('click', HIDE_IT)` and stop-event-propogation!

Comment: I am a bit weak in javascript, can you please tell me where to put it, i mean i have to amend and put this code in my current javascript or i have to put it separately?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  //your close function
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Put that code anywhere in your `$(document).ready(...` block